# Нужен ли nginx для node.js сервера?

Tags: node.js, nginx

Нужно ли ставить nginx перед нодой?

У нас в компании занимаются поиском Т-функции у новичков, и поэтому на новый проект я назначен главным backdoor разработчиком.

До этого ребята у нас ставили nginx перед нодой
и имели, с моей точки зрения кучу, проблем и неявных состояний.
Например между nginx и нодой рвется ws соединения, но nginxs об этом никому ничего не говорит.
А между клиентом и nginx соединение в порядке, но данные почему-то не приходят.
Пришлось городить свой пинг-понг.

На мой вопрос, а зачем вам вообще nginx, мне ответили что:
1) ничто так быстро не отдает статику как nginx;
2) в конце концов все всегда так делают.

Ну статику мы отдаем клиенту 1 раз и ее не так уж много.
А вот json'ы потом гоняем туда-сюда сутками, сгусями и с прочими птицами.
А по поводу того, что nginx отдает статику так быстро потому, что он ее никак не обрабатывает,
а видит из запроса что это "просто" статика и "просто" отдает ее (так мне объяснили) -
разве написав

```
арр.use(express.static( path.join(__dirname, '/static') ))
```

я не "просто" отдаю статику, никак ее не обрабатывая?

На своем проекте я пока стучусь непосредственно на ноду.
Прав ли я? Рационально ли это?
Или меня в будущем ждут непредвиденные трудности? На данном уровне моей квалификации мне кажется, что стучаться сразу на ноду - это само собой напрашивающийся шаг к отказу от ненужного усложнения системы и от ненужной прослойки. Действительно ли прослойка в виде nginx - ненужная?

Буду благодарен услышать Ваши комментарии.

Comment: Это будет работать до тех пор, пока нода вся такая единственная и неповторимая. Как только приспичит поставить более одного сайта на сервер (если хочется стандартные порты 80/443) или подадобится что-нибудь балансировать (что упомянули в ответе) — от nginx или аналога деться никуда не получится

Comment: А ещё использование стандартных портов 80/443 требует запуска от рута. А когда код сайта запускается от рута, это ОЧЕНЬ плохо: малейшая RCE-уязвимость — и злоумышленник без проблем получает полный доступ к серверу. С этой точки зрения если не конкретно nginx, то хоть какая-нибудь простенькая прокся должна быть, чтобы немножко спасти сервер от возможных уязвимостей

Comment: «Пришлось городить свой пинг-понг» — во-первых, пинги встроены в вебсокетный протокол и городить своё не надо, во-вторых, пинги в любом случае нужны, потому что отвалиться по таймауту может что угодно где угодно даже не на вашем сервере (например, мобильный оператор Теле2 обрубает TCP-соединения после пяти минут бездействия — из-за этого очень тяжело юзать на телефоне SSH и Opera Mini, например)

Comment: @andreymal оформите это всё ответом уже)

Comment: 1. `proxy_read_timeout 86400;` сделали, например? 2. без Nginx, NodeJS придется "кормить с ложечки" все медленные соединения. Сколько он так осилит?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Да, nginx добавляет сложности, требуя настроить себя, но по-моему это с лихвой компенсируется получаемыми плюшками.

**Масштабируемость**

Работать с одной-единственной нодой получится только до тех пор, пока на сервере находится один-единственный сайт. Однако в моей практике такого не было почти никогда: я как минимум ставлю ещё Munin для наблюдения за состоянием сервера. Придётся или вешать сайт на отдельный порт/айпишник (неудобно), или дописывать в ноде код для проксирования запросов на другой сайт (замусоривание кода всякими сложностями). В то время как в nginx новый сайт легко подключить парой строчек в конфиге.

Ещё один пример — A/B тестирование: запускаем две разные версии сайта, половину пользователей направляем на одну версию сайта, половину на другую, сравниваем их поведение и решаем, какая версия сайта лучше. Если изменения значительные, то скорее всего придётся запустить две ноды, и опять же нужно каким-то чудом решать, какой пользователь на какую ноду будет отправлен. Опять же в nginx это делается парой строчек (split_clients).

Когда сайт станет большой и популярный, нода может перестать помещаться в одном процессе или одном сервере, и придётся запускать несколько экземпляров ноды или даже докупать новые серверы. nginx позволит равномерно распределить нагрузку между процессами/серверами, принимая все запросы на себя и пересылая его на один из случайно выбранных процессов/серверов (или не случайно — смотря как настроить).

**Безопасность**

Использовать стандартные порты 80/443 может только root. А когда код сайта запускается от рута, это ОЧЕНЬ плохо: малейшая RCE-уязвимость — и злоумышленник без проблем получает полный доступ к серверу. Если нода будет работать от рута, то малейшая уязвимость в коде сайта может позволить с лёгкостью получить контроль над сервером целиком (как с помощью RCE, так и с помощью чтения какого-нибудь `../../../../../../etc/shadow` и последующего подбора пароля от рута в оффлайне, например).

В идеале код должен быть максимально изолирован от всего (вплоть до помещения в изолированный Docker-контейнер <s>(ходят слухи, что докер ещё и для разработки и развёртывания очень удобен, но я не верю)</s>). Если нода будет изолирована от всех, то максимум, что получит злоумышленник — контроль над нодой. Ну и доступ к базе данных, если она используется. Это плохо, но не совсем плохо, потому что взломанную ноду можно просто выключить до исправления уязвимости. А вот выпнуть злоумышленника, получившего root, будет уже гораздо тяжелее (вплоть до необходимости отключения сервера от интернета и полной переустановки системы).

Но, допустим, вы [перекостыляли с роутингом или форками или пропатчили ядро или ещё что-то](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807) и в итоге каким-то чудом умудрились поднять ноду на порту 80/443 без root. Тогда пришло время вспомнить про HTTPS и сертификаты для него. Для работы SSL/TLS ноде нужен будет доступ к приватному ключу, и опять же, если злоумышленник откопает RCE-уязвимость, то он сможет прочитать приватный ключ и начать организовывать MitM-атаки. Если же HTTPS будет настроен на nginx и доступ к приватному ключу будет только у nginx, то злоумышленник обломается. (Хотя, конечно, налажать могут всегда и везде, [даже у nginx+openssl однажды утекали приватные ключи...](https://xkcd.ru/1354/) <s>поэтому переходим на libressl</s>)

Кроме того, есть ряд менее серьёзных атак, которые всё же могут подпортить нервы. Например, манипуляции с медленными HTTP-запросами. В nodejs была [уязвимость CVE-2013-4450](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/vulnerability/http-server-pipeline-flood-dos/), позволяющая завалить её HTTP pipelining запросами и тем самым скушать ресурсы сервера. Теоретически подобное, конечно, может найтись и в nginx, но всё же сама его архитектура неплохо спасает от подобных пакостей. При наличии nginx на ноду уже будут приходить белые и пушистые HTTP-запросы, доставляющие минимум проблем, в то время как всякий мусор будет отфильтрован или забуферизован самим nginx'ом. (Хотя от терабитных DDoS-атак ничего не спасёт, но не будем о грустном)

**Прочие плюшки**

Обязательно будут моменты, когда нода не будет работать (например, она может быть просто выключена на техработы). Без nginx пользователи получат просто какую-то невнятную ошибку браузера, уведомляющую о невозможности подключения. С nginx можно отдать статическую страницу с более понятным описанием ошибки и предложением сообщить о проблеме администраторам сайта, или же повесить плашку техработ и предложение подписаться на твиттер.

**Про вебсокеты**

Непонятно, что у вас за проблемы были — без подрбоностей понять, кто виноват и что делать, трудно; у меня всё проксируется через nginx вполне стабильно. А пинги должны быть в любом случае, потому что отвалиться по таймауту может что угодно где угодно даже не на вашем сервере (например, мобильный оператор Теле2 обрубает TCP-соединения после пяти минут бездействия). «Городить свой пинг-понг» не нужно, потому что эта фича встроена в протокол — не знаю, как именно вы реализуете вебсокеты в ноде, но пинги где-то там наверняка уже должны быть.

Answer (score 4):

> Например между nginx и нодой рвется ws соединения, но nginxs об этом
>   никому ничего не говорит. А между клиентом и nginx соединение в
>   порядке, но данные почему-то не приходят.

Видимо, криво настроили.

> 1) ничто так быстро не отдает статику как nginx;

Правда.

> я не "просто" отдаю статику, никак ее не обрабатывая?

Вы считываете файл средствами node.js и отдаёте в стрим. nginx, который на такие вещи заточен, явно будет быстрее.

> На своем проекте я пока стучусь непосредственно на ноду. Прав ли я?

Возможно пока правы.

> Рационально ли это?

Если сервис только для себя, то возможно.

> Или меня в будущем ждут непредвиденные трудности?

1. При росте нагрузок как будете масштабировать? Если бы вы использовали nginx, то могли бы поднять несколько node.js сервисов на разных портах, а балансили бы их с помощью nginx.
2. Если ваш сервис упадёт, что будете делать?
3. Если понадобится SSL соединение, что будете делать?

К тому же, если понадобится для статики в будущем CDN, то они очень хорошо умеют работать с nginx.

Comment: «Видимо, криво настроили» — а отказ от nginx упростил бы настройку ;)

Comment: @andreymal я с таким не сталкивался, если честно. У нас все локальные сервисы спрятаны за прокси nginx. За годы работы я не припомню случая, когда что-то ломалось между нашими сервисами и nginx.

Comment: Я в общем-то тоже, проксирую через nginx вебсокеты в питон — всё ок. Правда, предполагаю, что если вебсокет в основном простаивает, то он может отвалиться по какому-нибудь таймауту — возможно, это как раз случай автора. Но для такого всё же есть пинги

Comment: @Suvitruf Сервис сейчас находится в стадии тестирования. По ws отправлялся json каждые 4 секунды (предполагаемая рабочая нагрузка).

Answer (score 1):

NodeJs мелкие файлы отдает быстрее чем Nginx, тем не менее всю статику лучше отдавать через отдельный хост (CDN), даже какой-то самодельный cdn.mysite.com c Nginx на борту будет отличным решением.

NodeJs на голом железе действительно использовать не стоит.

Сейчас, стильно-модно-молодежно использовать Kubernetes, в нем точно необходимости в Nginx перед NodeJs нет так как там уже будет свой Ingress, который построен на Nginx. Так же в Kubernetes не будет проблем с сертификатами, плюс балансировка нагрузки тоже будет.

Удачи!