# HTTP веб приложение

Tags: json, node.js, http, websocket, веб-сервер

Я пишу своё веб приложение используя нативный модуль http. Да и в принципе имею цель сейчас не использовать сторонние фреймворки типа того же express, pasport.js и другие по возможности, как на сервере, так и на клиенте!

Я знаю что есть много подходов отдавать страницы, например по кусочкам юзеру, либо рендерить её на сервере и т.д. Насколько будет хорош мой подход, о котором я напишу ниже?

Я при старте сервера загружаю всю статику в оперативную память (все css, js, html...), дабы потом быстро отдавать их юзеру. В них хранится контент, который для всех юзеров будет одинаков. После того, как статика загрузилась и наша страница отобразилась - я делаю запросы на сервер для динамических данных (например информация о пользователе) в формате json. И добавляю это всё к уже загруженой странице.

Если это хороший способ, то что лучше использовать для запроса динамических данных http request, или websocket?

Comment: "необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ". Пишите как угодно, вы всё равно пошли по пути велосипедостроения, раз упорно не хотите готовые сторонние фреймворки - а значит опыт вы получите в любом случае и разберётесь более детально, как всё работает "под капотом".

Comment: «всю статику в оперативную память» — статикой должен заниматься не nodejs, а nginx, и она автоматически кешируется в памяти операционной системой без дополнительных действий с вашей стороны

Comment: «я делаю запросы на сервер» — сайт не сможет работать без javascript и, помимо недовольных пользователей, проиндексируется не всеми поисковиками

Comment: @andreymal на юзеров, которые отключают JS, можно забить.

Comment: @andreymal у меня js тоже передаётся клиенту. А если юзер захочет отключить js - то я в любом случае не смогу работать с ним. Т.к. мне в любом случае их нужно как-то регистрировать, авторизовывать и взаимодействовать с ними.

Comment: @Suvitruf я полон желания поколотить считающих так разработчиков

Comment: @KiiDii ни одна из перечисленных вами вещей не требует javascript

Comment: @andreymal. Так-же вопрос про nginx. Почему нельзя в оперативке хранить статику и нужно использовать ещё один сервер?

Comment: @KiiDii потому что nginx сделает это лучше.

Comment: @KiiDii потому что nginx, во-первых, капитально заточен именно под эффективную раздачу статики, а во-вторых, [улучшает масштабируемость и безопасность сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/880851)

Comment: @Suvitruf «ни одна из перечисленных вами вещей не требует javascript». И как же мне тогда сделать запрос в базу данных, чтобы сохранить данные юзера? Вряд-ли это можно сделать на html или css.

Comment: @KiiDii работа с базой данных ни в коем случае не должна делаться на стороне пользователя, этим должен заниматься код на сервере. Пользователю при этом можно передать ровно ноль строчек javascript'а без каких-либо проблем с этим

Comment: @andreymal «потому что nginx сделает это лучше.» Ну тогда юзать готовые фреймворки - это намного лучше. Я пока из ваших комментариев не посчитал nginx лучше.

Comment: @andreymal Про GET POST запросы я забыл. Окей. А если я не хочу перезагружать страницы при отправке формы и взаимодействовать с юзером не как статичный сайт, а как динамическое веб приложение?

Comment: Мне уже пять лет хочется колотить тех, кто делает веб-приложения (особенно Microsoft за их новый Skype), но это уже моё сугубо личное мнение и дальше продолжать эту ветку разговора смысла мало)

Comment: @andreymal Ну тот же чат если мы будем делать, то явно перезагружать сайт через каждое n-секунд - это не лучшее решение. Разве нет? То-есть для всего должен быть свой подход. Так-вот мне нужно будет очень часто общаться с сервером, поэтому просто веб сайт мне не подходит.

Comment: @andreymal и что если я захочу показать на главной странице какие-то посты? Я должен каждую страницу генерировать отдельно? У меня так банально не хватит ресурсов.

Comment: Я считаю, что браузер - это не то место, где должны делаться чаты. Но если отбросить моё сугубо личное мнение, то для чатов лучше всего подходят вебсокеты. // Да, генерируйте каждую страницу отдельно - большинство сайтов делают именно так (в том числе Stack Overflow и, например, ВКонтакте, мобильная версия которого может работать с отключенным js кстати), от этого ещё никто не умер, и про нехватку ресурсов вы что-то напутали

Comment: Вы не забывайте так-же про удобство использования приложения. Юзеру при регистрации гораздо приятнее наблюдать за тем, что его логин уже используется без перезагрузки страницы. Или прогружать посты в том же вк опять же без перезагрузки страницы, а сразу, как только юзер долистает до последнего отображенного поста. Я не вижу адекватной причины отключать js в браузере. И таким юзерам нужно писать, что требуется включить js прежде чем использовать этот сайт. Это как зачем-то поддерживать юзеров, которые до сих пор сидят на ie7-8. Зачем тогда новые фишки?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89966/discussion-between-andreymal-and-kiidii).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну собственно, с точки зрения фронт энд вы пошли по пути Ajax, то есть создаёте `xmlhttprequest`. Это старый, простой и надежный способ. Запрос и сразу ответ. И забыли.

Недавно ковырялся с одной очень дорогой камерой от Sony, у них веб интерфейс так сделан и похоже не менялся 15 лет.

`WebSocket` более продвинутый вариант, он необходим, если Вам необходимо наладить двусторонний оперативный обмен данными клиента с сервером. Один раз создаёте соединение и потом и сервер и клиент могут туда писать и читать оттуда, формат бинарный.

В html5 Есть ещё **Server Sent Events**, они позволяют, единожды установив соединение с сервером, получать от него короткие текстовые сообщения

Comment: На замену XMLHttpRequest давно появился fetch

Comment: @andreymal умышленно не пишу про fetch, потому что в том окружении в котором например работаю я, от фетча есть только полифилл

Comment: Вот именно потому, что есть полифилл, и стоит смело писать про fetch :)