# Почему при запуске сервера на uwsgi часто используют nginx в качестве прокси?

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

Я видел много статей как люди запускают uwsgi сервера, прописывая файлы конфигурации, и nginx сервер как обратный прокси, который уже общается с wsgi. Какие в этом преимущества?

Comment: Там про node.js, но всё то же самое относится и к uwsgi: [Нужен ли nginx для node.js сервера?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/880851)

Comment: Ну и до кучи, браузеры не умеют wsgi, так что кто-то должен перевести http в wsgi.

Comment: @AlexeyTen uwsgi умеет http (и даже https), так что для него неактуально