# Настройка NGINX для создания API?

Tags: nginx

Имеется приложение на Flutter, которое должно получать/записывать данные в БД (MySQL) - расположенную на удаленном сервере.
На том же сервере, где работает MySQL - будет работать  Nginx.

Задача в следующем - создать API, при обращении к которому можно будет взимодействовать с БД, например:

- по адрессу 1.2.3.4:12345/tickets/create?id=1&name=test - добавлять запись в БД
- по адрессу 1.2.3.4:12345/tickets/get?id=1 - получать запись из БД - по указанному ид.

Т.е. внутри приложения - на определенные действия - будут прописанный маршруты к API - примерно такие, как привидены выше.

- до этого никогда не работал с настройкой севреров и Nginx - в частности. Как грамотно реалезовать задуманное?

P.S. - сейчас тестирую развернув виртуальную машину со стороны которой - есть свой NAT, но в дальнейшем - сервер с БД и Nginx - будет иметь белый ип.

Из того что находил сам по этой теме:

- Цикл из 3х статтей - https://www.nginx.com/blog/deploying-nginx-plus-as-an-api-gateway-part-1/ - начал читать, но не уверен, что это именно  то, что нужно, поэтому решил спросить здесь.

Comment: NGINX не решает такие задачи. Если вам надо взаимодействовать с базой данных, а тем более реализовать некий API то делайте это на каком нибудь языке программирования. А nginx при этом будет использоваться по своему прямому назначению - для передачи запросов в этот язык и ответов обратно. И со стороны nginx там будет всего несколько строк на подобии proxy_pass. Что конкретно используется лучше читать в статьях по конкретному языку программирования

Comment: Собственно это нарисовано на первой же картинке в статье, которую вы начали читать по NGINX. Там от представлен как API gatewey, т.е. шлюз, а справа от него есть некие "service", вот эти серввисы надо написать самостоятельно на языке программирования, не имеющего никакого отношения к nginx

Comment: Спасибо, понял. Можете оформить комментарии - как ответ - отмечу как верный.

Comment: @Mike, и если можно - сюда же, еще один вопрос задам - по теме. Какую роль тогда играет Nginx/Apache ? Т.е. условно говоря, если логика обращения к БД у меня написанна на одном из ЯП - PHP\Python\ JS (NodeJS) , то я могу просто обратиться к услвоному PHP-скрипту, который выдаст мне ответ? Например, mysite/get_info.php?some_param=1. Насколько я понял сервер отвечает за политики безопасности, маршрутизацию и по-сути - бекенд на ЯП - отдает уже статическую странциу - которую и возвращает сервер? Т.е. почему для обращения к скрипту - вообще нужен сервер, если я могу получить ответ напрямую?

Comment: Вот конкретно PHP вам не ответит вовсе, ибо он сам на некоем порту не висит и протокол http не поддерживает. для этого есть внешняя программа, которая по запросу извне запускает скрипт и отдает ответ. И такой программой обычно является apache или какая то прослойка со стороны nginx (но не сам он, не вдавался в подробности). А вот node, python как раз обычно сами обслуживают http и в принципе nginx им не особо нужен. Но когда у вас помимо одного api есть например статические файлы или несколько разных сервисов или много копий одного сервиса, вот тут nginx все это собирает вместе на одном домене

Comment: ЯП отдает просто "ответ", сферический в вакууме. Это может быть как страница html выглядящая как статическая, а может просто данные в json, что в вашем случае (и во многих других) гораздо разумнее.

Comment: Подозреваю, что связанный вопрос: [Нужен ли nginx для node.js сервера?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/880851)

Comment: Да, спасибо, отметил как ответ)