# запуск приложения React по https протоколу на сервере Ubuntu

Tags: reactjs

Есть приложение на  React (клиентская часть) и приложение на NodeJS(express) на порту 5000.
Имеется коммерческий SSL сертификат  (файлы .crt, .key). Подскажите, как запустить React приложение на сервере Ubuntu с использованием сертификата на https протоколе, без использования дополнительного веб-сервера

Comment: Использовать дополнительный веб-сервер. [Нужен ли nginx для node.js сервера?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/880851)